# Inclusion-Exclusion question

Tags: combinatorics, inclusion-exclusion, extremal-combinatorics

A careless payroll clerk is placing employees’ paychecks into pre-labeled envelopes. The envelopes are sealed before the clerk realizes he didn’t match the names on the paychecks with the names on the envelopes. If there are seven employees, in how many ways could he have placed the paychecks into the envelopes so that exactly three employees receive the correct paycheck?

Is it $6^4$?

Comment: Why do you think it's $6^4$?

Comment: I had thought that each of the employees whose envelope did not match their name had 6 options of what envelope would be given to him.

Comment: So then I got 6*6*6*6*1*1*1

Comment: where the three 1's were the fixed 3 employees who received the correct paycheck

Comment: There are several things wrong with this argument. First, you have to enumerate over the choice of the fixed employees. Second, you are drastically overcounting the number of possible values for each of the other employees. For one, once you take into account the three fixed employees, every other one has at most 3 choices left (other than herself).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $d_n$ be the number of derangements (permutations without fixed points) on $n$ points, that is
$$ d_n = n! \left(1 - \frac{1}{1!} + \frac{1}{2!} - \frac{1}{3!} + \cdots \pm \frac{1}{n!}\right). $$
The number of permutations of $n$ elements having exactly $k$ fixed points is
$$
\binom{n}{k} d_{n-k}.
$$
The first factor gives the number of choices for the fixed points, and the second factor gives the number of choices for the other coordinates. The sequence $d_n$ starts (indexed from $0$)
$$
1, 0, 1, 2, 9, 44, 265, 1854, \ldots.
$$
Therefore the number of permutations of $n = 7$ with $k = 0,\ldots,7$ fixed points is
$$
1854, 1855, 924, 315, 70, 21, 0, 1.
$$

Comment: Aren't there k=0,1,2,3 fixed points?

Comment: The answer you are looking for is 315. But there are permutations with 0,1,2,3,4,5,7 fixed points (but not with 6 fixed points, for obvious reasons).

Comment: Okay, thank you, Yuval!